# SSIS package shows as modified upon opening

Tags: ssis

I know I've read about this happening but I cannot seem to find the right keywords when googling. When I open up a package in BIDS it shows as modified right away even though I have just opened the package. In some cases if I step away or work on a solution for an extended period of time I forget if I actually edited the package. It's not the end of the world but I'd like to understand why this happens and if it can be prevented. If someone can explain or point me to some resources I'd appreciate it.